# Creating class instance properties from a dictionary?

Tags: class, python, komodo

I'm importing from a CSV and getting data roughly in the format

```
{ 'Field1' : 3000, 'Field2' : 6000, 'RandomField' : 5000 }
```

The names of the fields are dynamic. (Well, they're dynamic in that there might be more than Field1 and Field2, but I know `Field1` and `Field2` are always going to be there.

I'd like to be able to pass in this dictionary into my class `allMyFields` so that I can access the above data as properties.

```
class allMyFields:
    # I think I need to include these to allow hinting in Komodo. I think.
    self.Field1 = None
    self.Field2 = None

    def __init__(self,dictionary):
        for k,v in dictionary.items():
            self.k = v
            #of course, this doesn't work. I've ended up doing this instead
            #self.data[k] = v
            #but it's not the way I want to access the data.

q = { 'Field1' : 3000, 'Field2' : 6000, 'RandomField' : 5000 }
instance = allMyFields(q)
# Ideally I could do this.
print q.Field1
```

Any suggestions? As far as why -- I'd like to be able to take advantage of code hinting, and importing the data into a dictionary called `data` as I've been doing doesn't afford me any of that.

(Since the variable names aren't resolved till runtime, I'm still going to have to throw a bone to Komodo - I think the `self.Field1 = None` should be enough.)

So - how do I do what I want? Or am I barking up a poorly designed, non-python tree?

Comment: You don't need class attributes for Komodo Edit hinting.  It can read an `__init__` method body to find `self.` variables.   More fundamentally, why aren't you using a simple `csv.DictReader` for this and creating dictionaries from each row?

Comment: SLott - I modify the headers manually with re.sub() and add in a 'fake' header. It's not a really good reason, but renaming the key after a DictReader is a lot more expensive.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#setattr) (be careful though: not every string is a valid attribute name!):

```
>>> class AllMyFields:
...     def __init__(self, dictionary):
...         for k, v in dictionary.items():
...             setattr(self, k, v)
... 
>>> o = AllMyFields({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> o.a
1
```

**Edit:** let me explain the difference between the above code and [SilentGhost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639174/creating-class-instance-properties-from-a-dictionary-in-python/1639215#1639215). The above code snippet creates a class of which *instance attributes* are based on a given dictionary. SilentGhost's code creates a class whose *class attributes* are based on a given dictionary.

Depending on your specific situation either of these solutions may be more suitable. Do you plain to create one or more class instances? If the answer is one, you may as well skip object creation entirely and only construct the type (and thus go with SilentGhost's answer).

Comment: The code with the bonus edit explaining the differences between both good answers was really helpful, thanks!

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised to find this solution worked with a form_dict = flask.form.to_dict() to create a db.Model instance from a long web form.  Amazing!

Comment: Note- integers and floats entered on the form come back as strings in the form_dict but easily fixed before use by the class.

Answer (score 43):

```
>>> q = { 'Field1' : 3000, 'Field2' : 6000, 'RandomField' : 5000 }
>>> q = type('allMyFields', (object,), q)
>>> q.Field1
3000
```

docs for [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) explain well what's going here (see use as a constructor).

*edit*: in case you need instance variables, the following also works:

```
>>> a = q()             # first instance
>>> a.Field1
3000
>>> a.Field1 = 1
>>> a.Field1
1
>>> q().Field1           # second instance
3000
```

Comment: +1, but I do think you should explain the OP what this code does and/or give links to the documentation.

Comment: Well I guess his name *is* "SilentGhost"

Comment: Neat approach, but the fact that they're class variables is less compelling than instance variables.

Comment: you could instantiate `q` if required.

Comment: that's a very good trick

Answer (score 20):

You can also use `dict.update` instead of manually looping over `items` (and if you're looping, `iteritems` is better).

```
class allMyFields(object):
    # note: you cannot (and don't have to) use self here
    Field1 = None
    Field2 = None

    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.__dict__.update(dictionary)

q = { 'Field1' : 3000, 'Field2' : 6000, 'RandomField' : 5000 }
instance = allMyFields(q)

print instance.Field1      # => 3000
print instance.Field2      # => 6000
print instance.RandomField # => 5000
```

Comment: Any easy fix if the keys have spaces in them? Example: `instance.Something Else` won't work because of the space. I'm wondering if there's an elegant solution to this.

Comment: @Jarad instead of just `dictionary`, use `map(lambda kv: (kv[0].replace(' ', '_'), kv[1]), dictionary.items())`. This replaces all spaces in all key names with underscores.

Answer (score 9):

You could make a subclass of `dict` which allows attribute lookup for keys:

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

q = AttributeDict({ 'Field1' : 3000, 'Field2' : 6000, 'RandomField' : 5000 })
print q.Field1              
print q.Field2              
print q.RandomField
```

If you try to look up an attribute that `dict` already has (say `keys` or `get`), you'll get that `dict` class attribute (a method).  If the key you ask for doesn't exist on the `dict` class, then the `__getattr__` method will get called and will do your key lookup.

Answer (score 6):

Use setattr for the pretty way. The quick-n-dirty way is to update the instance internal dictionary:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__dict__.update({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
>>> a.foo
1
>>> a.bar
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using named tuples (Python 2.6):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple

>>> the_dict = {'Field1': 3, 'Field2': 'b', 'foo': 4.9}
>>> fields = ' '.join(the_dict.keys())
>>> AllMyFields = namedtuple('AllMyFields', fields)
>>> instance = AllMyFields(**the_dict)

>>> print instance.Field1, instance.Field2, instance.foo
3 b 4.9
```

Answer (score 4):

enhanced of [sub class of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639632/6494418)

recurrence dict works!

```py
class AttributeDict(dict):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639632/6494418"""

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name] if not isinstance(self[name], dict) \
            else AttributeDict(self[name])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {"hello": 1, "world": 2, "cat": {"dog": 5}}
    d = AttributeDict(d)
    print(d.cat)
    print(d.cat.dog)
    print(d.cat.items())

    """
    {'dog': 5}
    5
    dict_items([('dog', 5)])
    """
```

Comment: Upvoted as I do like this and it answers the question, but my main reason for having properties is for intellisense/autocomplete in a RAD Enviro (e,g, PyCharm). This doesnt deliver that.

Answer (score 4):

If you are open for adding a new library, pydantic is a very efficient solution. It uses python annotation to construct object and validate type Consider the following code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: str


data = {"name": "ahmed", "age": 36}

p = Person(**data)
```

pydantic: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/

Answer (score 3):

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,
                 property1,
                 property2):
       self.property1 = property1
       self.property2 = property2


property_dict = {'property1': 'value1',
                 'property2': 'value2'}
sc = SomeClass(**property_dict)
print(sc.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this

```
class AllMyFields:
    def __init__(self, field1, field2, random_field):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        self.random_field = random_field

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, d: dict):
        return cls(**d)


a = AllMyFields.get_instance({'field1': 3000, 'field2': 6000, 'random_field': 5000})
print(a.field1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for Python >= 3.7 is

```py
field_dict = { 'Field1' : 3000, 'Field2' : 6000, 'RandomField' : 5000 }

# Using dataclasses
from dataclasses import make_dataclass
field_obj = make_dataclass("FieldData", field_dict)(**field_dict)
```

Or using attrs library

```py
# Using attrs
from attrs import make_class
field_obj = make_class("FieldData", list(field_dict))(**field_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build an init class and introduce parameters in the class constructor, a simple alternative would be to use the dict.update method after the class has been created.

```
class Foo:
    attr1:str
    attr2:str


d = {'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2'}
foo = Foo()
foo.__ dict __.update(d)
```

This approach provides the flexibility of maintaining a clean constructor and simple class definition.  It also allows you the option to manually populate instance values (e.g. foo.attr1 = 'somevalue') when the dictionary key names do not exactly match attribute names.