# How to directly access class instances through class dictionary in Python

Tags: python, oop, agent-based-modeling

I need a way of accessing directly an instance of a class through an ID number.

As I tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583195/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-class-instances-with-single-attributes-read-from/10583317#comment13785524_10583317), I am importing a .csv file and I want to create an instance of my class Person() for every line in the .csv file, plus I want to be able to directly access these instances using as a key a unique identifier, already present in the .csv file.

What I have done so far, thanks to the help of user433831, is this:

```
from sys import argv
from csv import DictReader
from person import Person

def generateAgents(filename):
  reader = DictReader(open(filename, 'rU'))
  persons = [Person(**entry) for entry in reader]
  return persons
```

where person is just the module where I define the class Person() as:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, **kwds):
    self.__dict__.update(kwds)
```

Now I have a list of my person instances, namely `persons`, which is already something neat.
But now I need to create a network among these persons, using the `networkx` module, and I definitely need a way to access directly every person (at present my instances don't have any name).

For example, every person has an attribute called "father_id", which is the unique ID of the father. Persons not having a father alive in the current population has a "father_id" equal to "-1".

Now, to link every person to his/her father, I'd do something like:

```
import networkx as nx 
G=nx.Graph() 
for person in persons: 
  G.add_edge(person, person_with_id_equal_to_father_id)
```

My problem is that I am unable to access directly this "person_with_id_equal_to_father_id".
Keep in mind that I will need to do this direct access many many times, so I would need a pretty efficient way of doing it, and not some form of searching in the list (also considering that I have around 150000 persons in my population).

It would be great to implement something like a dictionary feature in my class Person(), with the key of every instance being a unique identifier. This unique identifier is already present in my csv file and therefore I already have it as an attribute of every person.

Thank you for any help, as always greatly appreciated. Also please keep in mind I am a total python newbie (as you can probably tell... ;) )

Comment: have you considered using a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a dictionary:

```
persons_by_id = {p.id: p for p in persons}
```

This requires a recent version of Python. If yours doesn't support this syntax, use the following:

```
persons_by_id = dict((p.id, p) for p in persons)
```

Having done either of the above, you can locate the person by their id like so:

```
persons_by_id[id]
```

The `networkx` example becomes:

```
import networkx as nx 
G=nx.Graph() 
for person in persons: 
  if person.father_id != -1:
    G.add_edge(person, persons_by_id[person.father_id])
```

Comment: another option would be to directly create that dictionary instead of a list in the generateAgents function

Comment: Thanks! It was so easy! I love python! :)
@Toote: yes, it would be even more efficient (can you suggest a way to do it?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient way to do what @Toote suggests:

```
def generateAgents(filename):
  with open(filename, 'rU') as input:
    reader = DictReader(input)
    persons = dict((entry['father_id'], Person(**entry)) for entry in reader)
  return persons
```