# Creating class instance from dictionary?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create class instance from dictionary that has keys more than class has attributes. I already read answers on the same question from this link: [Creating class instance properties from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639174/creating-class-instance-properties-from-a-dictionary). The problem is that I can't write `__init__` in class definition as I want, because I'm using SQLAlchemy declarative style class definition. Also `type('className', (object,), dict)` creates wrong attributes that are not needed.
Here is the solution that I found:

```
dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
object = MyClass(**dict)
```

But it does not work if dict has redundant keys:

```
dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'redundant_value'}
object = MyClass(**dict) # here need to ignore redundant_key
```

Are there any solutions except direct deleting all redundant keys from `dict`?

Comment: What is a `redundant_key`?

Comment: How do you want to write `__init__` for `MyClass`? Sorry I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy declarative style class definitions.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso redundant_key is a key that exists in a dictionary, but doesn't exist in class attributes.

Comment: @PaulRooney `__init__` for MyClass such as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639197/3700561

Comment: So you know which keys will be input?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Yes, I exactly know all class' attributes and dict keys and I can directly remove all "wrong keys" from dict and then use the solution that is mention above. But I don't think this is a right way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `classmethod` to filter the dict and return the object.

You then dont have to force your `__init__` method to accept a dict.

```
import itertools

class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def fromdict(cls, d):
        allowed = ('key1', 'key2')
        df = {k : v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in allowed}
        return cls(**df)

    def __init__(self, key1, key2):
        self.key1 = key1
        self.key2 = key2

dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'redundant_value'}

ob = MyClass.fromdict(dict)

print ob.key1
print ob.key2
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is to [Filter dict to contain only certain keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3420122/584846):

```
dict_you_want = { your_key: dict[your_key] for your_key in your_keys }
```

Comment: And then add a line in your __init__function like:`self.__dict__.update(dict_you_want)`

Answer (score 1):

One of the special python **magic methods** of an object is  `object.__dict__` *"A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes."* 
So, by elevating this feature...

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, **entries):
      self.__dict__.update(entries))

dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'redundant_value'}

ob = MyClass(**dict)
```

Note: It doesn't handle nested dictionary...