# Is there any way to get class instance attributes without creating class instance?

Tags: python, dictionary, class-instance-variables

Here is the link to my first question: [Creating class instance from dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113723/creating-class-instance-from-dictionary) 
 So I am trying to create class instance from dictionary which holds keys that class has not. For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.attr1 = value1
        self.attr2 = value2

dict = {'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'value3'}
```

Before creating class instance I have to delete this `redundant_key` from dict

```
dict.pop('redundant_key', None)
new_instance = MyClass(**dict)
```

The problem is that I have several classes and several dicts with a lot of keys (I have several responses in json format which are represented as dicts and I want to create objects from this json responses). I already found an interim solution from previous question - how to delete redundant keys. I can create new dict from old dict only with keys that I need:

```
new_dict = {key: old_dict[key] for key in allowed_keys}
```

So here is the code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.attr1 = value1
        self.attr2 = value2

dict = {'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'value3'}
new_instance = MyClass(**{key: dict[key] for key in allowed_keys})
```

All I need now is to get `allowed_keys`. So the question - Is there any way to get class instance attributes without creating class instance?

Comment: first, it is not possible, second, you want to get the arguments of a function, and not the attributes of a instance, which is possible by inspection.

Comment: It's technically impossible, attributes can be added and removed dynamically to instances, so it doesn't make sense to have them with out an actual instance. I am not sure why would you want it, where is the `allowed_keys` defined?

Comment: @Daniel All I need is to get `attr1` and `attr2` in  `allowed_keys` when `attr1`, `attr2` are class instance' attributes

Comment: @luk32 I can define allowed_keys with myself but its about 10 dicts with 10-20 different keys so I thought about way to fill allowed_keys automatically. I don't really need class instance' attributes I need attributes that are creating during `__init__` method

Comment: Looking at your use case, looks like what you need is *not* the attributes that `__init__` will create, but its argument signature: The arguments it accepts. That's a different problem, and it has a solution :-)

Comment: @alexis: that's what I said 17min ago. But the OP won't listen :-(

Comment: You mean "unnecessary", not "redundant".

Comment: @chepner Yes, I am sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using an overly general dictionary to initialize your object, just define [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) to accept, but ignore, the extra keys.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, **kwargs):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2

d = {'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2', 'extra_key': 'value3'}
new_instance = MyClass(**d)
```

If you can't modify [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) (as appears to be the case if it inherits from a SQLAlchemy declarative base), add an alternate constructor to accept all the keyword arguments but pick out the ones you need.

```
class MyClass(Base):
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, **kwargs):
        # Let any KeyErrors propagate back to the caller.
        # They're the one who forgot to make sure **kwargs
        # contained the right keys.
        value1 = kwargs['attr1']
        value2 = kwargs['attr2']
        return cls(value1, value2)

new_instance = MyClass.from_dict(**d)
```

Comment: You've broken one of the most basic rules of Python programming by naming a variable the same as a built-in...

Comment: No, I copied the user's original code and didn't bother to change it.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This answers what OP was asking about (getting attributes of an instance), not what they needed. Which seems to be constructor's parameter list.*

You cannot do what you want. In python attributes are added to an instance of a class dynamically. Two instances of the same class can have different attributes. Well... to be precise, there are things called *instance* attributes, and *class* attributes.

Instance attributes are the ones associated with the instance of a class. Class attributes are associated with its definition i.e. if you wrote (`MyClass.foo`)

If you look at the example, the attributes are added during the `__init__` on `self` so they are instance attributes.

What you could do is to create a valid instance and inspect it (look at below *example*), provide a static list of `allowed_keys` (e.g. as a class attribute), or in some way require `allowed_keys` as constructor parameter. All of these are kind of workarounds as what you really need is impossible. They have their pros and cons.

*example*:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.attr1 = value1
        self.attr2 = value2

instance = MyClass(1,2)                        # create a valid object
instance_attributes = instance.__dict__.keys() # inspect it
print(instance_attributes)
```

Comment: I don't really need class instance' attributes I need attributes that are creating during `__init__` method. Is there any way to get attributes that are added during in `__init__` method ?

Comment: A case where there _is_ a notion of class attributes is when a class has `__slots__` instead of an attribute dictionary.

Comment: This solution can have side effects, won't work in each case and you already need to know the parameters of `__init__` to instanciate the class.

Comment: I am not saying this is a good idea. Also you do know the number of parameters, not the names of attributes which seems to be needed.

Comment: @Daniel I think I got you. I wrote a little disclaimer. The question is kind of misleading. Plus, I think above ideas are the only solutions that will work with `*args` and `**kwargs`. I think the answer still has some value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do what you're trying to do: Instantiate your classes with appropriate arguments. Note that you're not examining the attributes that `__init__` creates, but **the arguments it accepts.** It doesn't matter what it does with them-- that's not your concern when you're calling the constructor.

```
myparams = {'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'value3'}
usable = { k:v for k, v in myparams if k in MyClass.__init__.__code__.co_varnames }
new_instance = MyClass(**usable)
```

I used a filtered dictionary comprehension for clarity, but you could do it in one step of course.

PS. Note that you'll have a problem if one of your dictionaries happens to contain the key `self`. :-) You may want to filter it out if you can't trust your data source.

Comment: This is a really good solution, but the problem is that class which I have is creating by sqlalchemy. I am just write it according to the declarative class definition style. So MyClass.__init__.__code__.co_varnames returns something like that `('self', 'kwargs', 'new_state')` and I just can't write `__init__` method as I want

Comment: In that case your question should be specific to sqalchemy! You'd have to dig around its internals to find out what arguments are accepted by the classes you are interested in. There may be something you can use (perhaps its initializers have a standard way of managing the allowed keyword arguments), or there may not. In general you cannot expect to know what a function will do, without either running it or simulating it.

Comment: I also strongly suspect that the attributes created will depend on the keyword arguments you provide-- meaning that even if you can instantiate the constructor without arguments to instantiate a sample object, you won't see all possible attributes in the instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

You should have mentioned, that you want the columns of a SQLAlchemy-Mapper-Class. This is a much easier task:

```
dict = {'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2', 'redundant_key': 'value3'}
columns = YourTable.__table__.columns.keys()
entry = YourTable(**{k: dict[k] for k in columns})
```