# Python classes, Can i find all instances which have a predefined attributes?

Tags: python, class, variables

I'am wondering if it exist a command by which i can get all instances that have a predefined attributes ? , Here is an example code :

```
class Doors:
def __init__(self, length, width, color):
    self.length = length
    self.width = width
    self.color = color
```

after receiving some Doors , i want to get all doors which has the same color !

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129147) might have what you want, does that help?

Comment: "after receiving some Doors " what does this mean, *exactly*? Please try to be specific. Giving example input data and expected output really helps.