# Using type() to populate custom class object in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Background**

I have a custom class where 1 particular attribute is dependent on another. Working with python 2.7

I know, not a good design, but that's what it is for now

```
class CrazyClass(object):
    def __init__():
        self.entity = None  # This will be None initialized. Later populated as a dict
        self._status = 'undefined'

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, value):
        self._status = value
        try:
            self.entity["Status"] = value
        except Exception:
            raise Exception("'entity' should be defined before specifying 'status'")
```

So basically, if you wish to set `status`, `entity` should have already been defined

**Requirement**

I need to dump the class object in a file and then later read it and recreate the object instance

I am not using pickle/unpickle and instead dumping the attributes and values as key/value pairs in a dictionary.

Instead I am trying to use `type(name, bases, dict)` method

**The Dilemma**

While it seems to work fine but I am really skeptical if it will always work ??

```
type('CrazyClass',(object,),dumped_dict)
```

Since `dict` is un-ordered, could there be case that `status` is populated before `entity` and this fails ?

Any insight on how `type` would work internally ?

Comment: "Since dict is un-ordered", not since python 3.5/3.6.

Comment: I didn't know that :). But anyways, I mentioned that code is in python 2.7

Comment: can't you use `collections.OrderedDict` then? and sort when you dump the elements? for instance sort the keys so entity comes before status in an OrderedDict, dump that, and use the same trick when reloading (load+sort and put in ordered dict)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I can do that. I wanted to understand that if this `type` invocation has the potential of failing in this case ? How it would work internally ?

Comment: um, `entity` and `_status` are instance attributes, so they shouldn't be in the dict passed to `type`, because that should only have class attributes

Comment: The `dict` argument to the `type` constructor can be any arbitrary mapping that implements (or defines all the methods for) the `collections.abc.Mapping` abstract base class.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix I didn't understand that comment

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was referring to an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639174/creating-class-instance-properties-from-a-dictionary which said that `type()` could be used

Comment: That answer explicitly states that the dict is not for instance variables

Comment: @mittal I was referring to your question to @Jean-FrançoisFabre. The third argument to `type` can be any dict-like object (anything with string keys, __getitem__, and a way to iterate through those keys). Abstract base classes are just Python's alternative to interfaces in languages like Java, C#, or Go.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions here. I believe reading through the link I posted again, carefully, I realized that `type()` is not the correct way to create object instances as was correctly pointed by @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'll work with the other `setattr` method