# Python json to object from model

Tags: python, json, object, model

I know this looks like Frequency Ask Question mainly this question: [How to convert JSON data into a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object)

I will mention most voted answer:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

data = '{"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}'

# Parse JSON into an object with attributes corresponding to dict keys.
x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
print(x.name, x.hometown.name, x.hometown.id)
```

Based on that answer, `x` is object. But it's not object from model. I mean model that created with class. For example:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Hometown:
  def __init__(self, name : str, id : int):
    self.name = name
    self.id = id


class Person:  # this is a model class
  def __init__(self, name: str, hometown: Hometown):
    self.name = name
    self.hometown = hometown


data = '{"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}'
x = Person(what should I fill here?) # I expect this will automatically fill properties from constructor based on json data 
print(type(x.hometown)) # will return Hometown class
```

I'm asking this is simply because my autocompletion doesn't work in my code editor if I don't create model class. For example if I type dot after object, it will not show properties name.

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639174/creating-class-instance-properties-from-a-dictionary
It's tricky if dict is nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve that.

```
class Person:  # this is a model class
    def __init__(self, name: str, hometown: dict):
        self.name = name
        self.hometown = Hometown(**hometown)


x = Person(**json.loads(data))
```

Comment: `print(x.hometown.id)` has return error `'dict' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: `print(x.hometown['id'])` this will return `123` no error. I expect I can access `id` with dot instead of square bracket.

Comment: You can do it it like this there is no problem: x.hometown.id

Comment: Okay my fault I didn't see you modified `Person` class in `hometown` property.